# How to get client's "Downloads" folder from server - Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I need download image to client's download folder. My web app, Running on a server. I use following code to do it.

```
 String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
 FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(home + "/Downloads/" + name)));
```

If I use this, It works perfectly on localhost. When I deploy it  in server, It takes server download path. So, Instead of server file path, I need to get local file path. How to do it?.

Comment: It is not possible. You can not Access the Client from the server

Comment: @Jens Is there a solution other than this. Like opening a "save as" file browser popup?

Comment: Yes that is possible. But to broad to explain it here

Comment: @Jens Thank You. Any reference links?